# How do I declare a variable that is accessible throughout the whole Rails application?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My application depends upon a variable `page_name` but the value in the variable `page_name` is set only after submitting a form.

Should I use a session? When I searched I found out that sessions will be destroyed if my application is behind a load-balancer.

What would be a better way to make a variable accessible throughout the whole Rails application?

Creating a constant could have solved my problem but the value in the variable is not set until the user fill the data in a form field and submits the data. So basically, the user is responsible to fill the value in the variable my whole application depends upon.

Comment: @HarishVed, please read the question again. I know that a constant will be accessible throught the app. But here, the value in the variable is not set until the user inserts a value in a form field and submits it

Comment: "the value in the variable is not set until the user inserts a value in a form field and submits it" And what's the problem? You can't use it before you know what the user is going to enter, so code needing it can't be called. If it does try then it sounds like your code has real problems. Once it's submitted you *could* set a global variable and use that, but globals are major code smell unless you know why you should use them. Use a database or an instance variable. As is, the question isn't well defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to persist the value in either the database (using ActiveRecord), or in a shared memcache server (assuming you can accept the variable will be lost if it is pushed out of cache).

You'll just set the database value for example in your controller create action just like any other model.

First, create the model

```
rails generate model variable_name variable_value
```

To save a value in it from your `def create` action:

```
@app_store = AppStore.find_or_initialize_by_name('variable_name')
@app_store.variable_value = secure_params[:variable_value]
@app_store.save
```

then retrieve from anywhere in your app with

```
@app_store = AppStore.find_by_name('variable_name')
val = @app_store.variable_value
```

Comment: Is there a way without using the database?

Comment: If you need persistence, even if the server goes down, then you'll need to write the value to a file on a file system shared across all servers behind the load balancer if you don't use a database. Since this is a rails app, I assumed you are already using a database. Are you not? If you are, what is your concern about using the database for persistence? It is what it is designed to do.

Comment: Well, after submitting the form , the value is not stored in the database. I was trying to put it in a variable that would be accessible throughout the whole app. But looks like I have to persist it into the database.

Comment: You can retrieve it from the database and store it in an instance variable in a `before_action` in your `ApplicationController`. Then it'll be always available in your controllers.

Comment: @Mischa yes, I will do that :)

Answer (score 1):

Sessions aren't neccesarily destroyed by a load balancer -- it depends on your session configuration AND your load balancer configuration/capabilities. But ordinarily sessions should work fine with a load balancer. But session variables *are* just available to.. that session. Is the value session-specific, or is it really global accross sessions?

If the latter, I'd just stick it in the database. Even make a new table for GlobalVariables or something, with just name and value.

It's a "hacky" solution, but it'll work fine, and is easy to do.

But as I re-read your question... nevermind, I don't think you actually want to do what you asked anyway. There's no reason you should need to create a "variable that is accessible through the whole rails app" to solve that problem. You shouldn't need sessions either. I'll let others try to answer your un-asked actual questions.

Answer (score 0):

`title` is a local variable. They only exists within its scope, which is the current block.

`@title` is a instance variable, and it is available to all methods within the class.

You can read more in "[Struggling With Ruby: Variables](http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.dk/2010/03/variables.html)".

In Ruby on Rails, declaring your variables in your controller as instance variables like `@title` makes them available to your view.

Comment: yes I know that, but I want a variable that is accessible to the whole app and not just to current block or class.